# How do you center a Hamburger menu when selected?

Tags: angular, material-design, hamburger-menu

[image: example here]
I have a hamburger menu in my web app and when you click on it the blue box is clearly not centered correctly around the menu icon. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

html

```
 <mat-toolbar color="primary" class="header-box-shadow">
  <button mat-icon-button (click)="navigation.toggle()" fxShow.sm="true" fxShow.gt-sm="true">
    <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
  </button>
```

css

```
.header-box-shadow {
  box-shadow: 0 3px 5px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.2), 0 6px 10px 0 
  rgba(0,0,0,.14), 0 1px 18px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12);
  justify-content: center;
 }
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a stackblitz? You can start from [this one](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u6nf7y-adgbts).

Comment: Is your `.header-box-shadow` element using flexbox? `justify-content` goes along with that display type only

Comment: @ConnorsFan yes will do that right now thanks

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel im not quite too sure but i will look into that